# Finding the Exact Probability Distribution for the Outcomes of a Quantum Circuit with Mid-Circuit Measurements

Tags: qiskit, measurement, simulation, probability

I would like to find the exact probabilities of the possible outcomes of a circuit that includes mid-circuit measurements.

So, as a specific example, consider the following circuit:

[image: Example circuit]

I would like to find the exact probabilities for all possible outcomes in the classical register (so no sampling). Does anyone have any idea of how to do that? The typical route of using Statevector from qiskit.quantum_info doesn't work here, because it can only deal with the final state of the qubits.

For clarity: I am working in qiskit, but I am happy to switch to whatever language this is possible in.

Comment: According to the Deferred Measurement Principle all measurements can be delayed until the end of quantum computation and this will not change the probability distribution of outcomes. 

The circuit that you posted is epic and I feel like it deserves to become a meme. I suggest reading the basic info about the gate $H$ and measurements before programming anything.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand that you could in principle defer measurements, simply by introducing an ancilla qubit and a CNOT. I'd rather not do that though because the circuits I am actually looking at have many mid-circuit measurements, so I would need an infeasible number of ancillas.

What I was trying to get is a simulator that would propagate the density matrix of the system, and then apply a dephasing channel when mid-circuit measurements are applied, all while remembering the outcome probabilities of the mid-circuit measurements. Do you know if qiskit supports that?

Comment: Deferring a measurement does not require CNOT or ancilla qubits. It means you can put all measurement gates at the end of computation.

Comment: How would you defer measurement in the example circuit above? Surely you would have to introduce another qubit to 'hold' the information of the mid circuit state, so you can measure them at the end?

Comment: The circuit above is absurd because it essentially repeats the same very trivial  computation twice. I did not give a formal stack answer to your question cause at first I thought you were trolling. Given that what you ask is super basic and there are still no formal answers suggests you should probably think more about your circuit and what you ask. I suggest to read about  the $H$ gate or wait till some generous person writes you an explanation on $H$ which you could probably google.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens if $|\psi\rangle$ = $|0\rangle$ or $|\psi\rangle$ = $|1\rangle$ is passed as an input to two Hadamard gates in sequence?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11614/what-happens-if-psi-rangle-0-rangle-or-psi-rangle-1-rangle-is)

Comment: Yeah, so I am definitely not trolling lol. I understand how a Hadamard gate works. This was just the simplest example I could come up with to which my question applies. The circuits I am actually considering are far more complicated, and I'd like to know if there's a way to exactly find the resulting density matrix.